# Replace words in HTML string by spans with title, except within certain tags

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.1

I looked around anywhere but I did not find a decent solution for this.

**I have an HTML string:**

```
$html = "<p>This an example string with a <a href='/link/to/example' title='Title to example'>link</a> and an <img src='path/to/example-image.jpg' alt='Alt text from example image'></p>"
```

**I have an array:**

```
$glossary = array(
    "example" => "<span class='tooltip'>This is the explanation</span>"
    ...
)
```

What I try to achieve is to replace the string 'image' in the html string without changing it in the IMG and A elements, basically all the elements in the exclude array:

```
$excludes = array('img','a',etc)
```

Comment: Your `$html` itself won't work. Look at the quotations!

Comment: You can achieve that using regular expressions. Here it was resolved: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3463425/6250357)